# SSRS 2005 column chart: show series label missing when data count is zero

Tags: t-sql, reporting-services, charts, reporting, reportingservices-2005

I have a pretty simple chart with a likely common issue.  I've searched for several hours on the interweb but only get so far in finding a similar situation.

the basics of what I'm pulling contains a created_by, person_id and risk score
the risk score can be:

1 VERY LOW
2 LOW
3 MODERATE STABLE
4 MODERATE AT RISK
5 HIGH
6 VERY HIGH

I want to get a headcount of persons at each risk score and display a risk count even if there is a count of 0 for that risk score but SSRS 2005 likes to suppress zero counts.

I've tried this in the point labels
=IIF(IsNothing(count(Fields!person_id.value)),0,count(Fields!person_id.value))

Ex: I'm missing values for "1 LOW" as the creator does not have any "1 LOW" they've assigned risk scores for.

[*here's a screenshot of what I get but I'd like to have a column even for a count when it still doesn't exist in the returned results.](https://www.dropbox.com/s/3ap9e2lprwsb4t1/cpci_no_1.JPG)

@Nathan

Example scenario:

`select professor.name, grades.score, student.person_id
from student

inner join grades on student.person_id = grades.person_id

inner join professor on student.professor_id = professor.professor_id

where
student.professor_id = @professor`

Not all students are necessarily in the grades table.

I have a =Count(Fields!person_id.Value) for my data points & series is grouped on =Fields!score.Value

If there were a bunch of A,B,D grades but no C & F's how would I show labels for potentially non-existent counts

Comment: Can you post the SQL you are using for the dataset? Ideally I would alter the query so that data was always returned for each value of risk score, i.e. if you have a table that defines the risk score values then this would become the left hand side of a LEFT OUTER JOIN. If the person has no rows for a particular value of risk score, then use ISNULL to set it to 0.

Comment: Another problem, I believe, is SQL Server Reporting Svcs 2005 will not graph zero counts by default.

Comment: Another problem, I believe, is SQL Server Reporting Svcs 2005 will not graph zero counts by default.  I've thought of persons w/o a score to set them to -1 or 0.  Or predefine the columns somehow so the labels still show.  Do switch statements or case statements somewhere... it's really what to do where :(  It's really weird.  Most examples deal with counting items falling under certain dates and, say, a month is skipped because there isn't an item that gets returned for one of the months, for example.

Comment: [this is about as close as I get](http://community.dynamics.com/crm/b/gonzaloruiz/archive/2012/05/22/how-to-force-zero-data-points-in-date-charts-ssrs.aspx) but it's an SSRS 2008 example and 2005 doesn't have some of the options 2008 has.  I'm going to read through it again & see what there's does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your example, the problem is that no results are returned for grades that are not linked to any students. To solve this ideally there would be a table in your source system which listed all the possible values of "score" (e.g. A - F) and you would join this into your query such that at least one row was returned for each possible value.

If such a table doesn't exist and the possible score values are known and static, then you could manually create a list of them in your query. In the example below I create a subquery that returns a combination of all professors and all possible scores (A - F) and then LEFT join this to the grades and students tables (left join means that the professor/score rows will be returned even if no students have those scores in the "grades" table).

```
SELECT 
    professor.name
  , professorgrades.score 
  , student.person_id
FROM
(
  SELECT professor_id, score
  FROM professor
  CROSS JOIN
   ( 
     SELECT 'A' AS score
     UNION
     SELECT 'B'
     UNION
     SELECT 'C'
     UNION
     SELECT 'D'
     UNION
     SELECT 'E'
     UNION
     SELECT 'F'
   ) availablegrades
 ) professorgrades
INNER JOIN professor ON professorgrades.professor_id = professor.professor_id
LEFT JOIN grades ON  professorgrades.score = grades.score
LEFT JOIN student ON grades.person_id = student.person_id AND 
              professorgrades.professor_id = student.professor_id

WHERE professorgrades.professor_id = 1
```

See a live example of how this works here: [SQLFIDDLE](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/c7ea7/31)

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT RS.RiskScoreId, RS.Description, SUM(DT.RiskCount) AS RiskCount
FROM (
    SELECT RiskScoreId, 1 AS RiskCount
    FROM People
    UNION ALL
    SELECT RiskScoreId, 0 AS RiskCount
    FROM RiskScores
) DT
INNER JOIN RiskScores RS ON RS.RiskScoreId = DT.RiskScoreId
GROUP BY RS.RiskScoreId, RS.Description
ORDER BY RS.RiskScoreId
```